# tumblr api 401 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, tumblr

I've got some code that is supposed to post some data to a authenticated user's blog:

```
var url = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/"+_ctx.blog.name+".tumblr.com/post",
    data = {
        type: 'text',
        title: _S.shareTitle,
        body: _S.shareDesc,
        api_key: 'CONSUMER_API_KEY'
    };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, status, error){
        console.log(status+' - '+error);
    }
});
```

But I'm getting a 401 Not Authorized error every time. I looked over the API documentation and see that the `blog/BLOGNAME/post` endpoint requires OAuth tokens to be set, but what is the parameter name for the access token? Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you passing in the api key from another js file? Also for _ctx.blog.name is that defined somewhere else? If you can create a fiddle it will then be possible to test the 401 error. I imagine you might not want to expose the api key, but it is unavoidable if you are using a js solution.

Comment: @lharby The key is currently hardcoded into the page, but I was going to do an ajax call to retrieve it so it's not just right out in the open. And yes, `_ctx.blog.name` is collected after the initial token is retrieved from Tumblr.